# Rails_admin add tab under Add new tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Hi is it possible to add a tab under add new tab in rails_admin? I want to separate some of the fields in different tab so I will have a clean navigation. But I don't know if rails_admin allows it.